# Working with multiple arrays and incrementing objects within them

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I have these classes:

```
public class EdgeI {
  public int from;
  public int to;

  public EdgeI (int a1, int a2) {
    from = a1;
    to = a2;
  }
}

public class VertexI {
  public List neighbors;
  public String info;

  public VertexI (List neig, String str) {
    neighbors = neig;
    info = str;
  }

}

public class vertexWeight {
  public int v;
  public int w;

  public vertexWeight (int vertexNum, int wum) {
    v = vertexNum;
    w = wum;
  }
}
```

Suppose I have a list of `EdgeI` objects that contain pairs of numbers. Suppose I also have a list of `VertexI` objects that contain an empty list and a string. I want to add the following to the empty list:

Suppose I have this as my list of EdgeI objects

```
(1,2), (1,2) (1,2), (1,3), (1,3), (1,4)
```

For the first `VertexI` object in the list, I want to add the following list

```
(2,3) (3,2)
```

to the vertex object. Basically I want to take the "to" integer and the number of times that "to" integer repeats and create `vertexWeight` objects to add to the list of `neig` from the `VertexI` class. So `neig` for the first `VertexI` object would be the `vertexWeight` objects `(2,3)` and `(3,2)`. To implement this I created this so far:

```
 public void createGraph () {
    int oldFrom = -1;
    int oldTo = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
      EdgeI e = edges.get(i);
      int from = e.from;
      int to = e.to;
      VertexI v = vertices.get(from);
      v.neighbors.add(new vertexWeight (to, 1));
      if (from == oldFrom && to == oldTo){}
        //have to add increment the number 1 in the vertex weight object somehow
      else {
        oldFrom = from;
        oldTo = to;
      }
    }
  }
```

I need some tips or methods to go about implementing this? My logic may be incorrect, thats where I need the most help I think.

Comment: Try to avoid "fake" code like your first code sample. Instead of listing syntactically incorrect constructor signatures, you include `public` or default access fields, and abbreviate the constructor bodies with `// ...` if you want brevity. (A good idea if the constructor can be generated by an IDE anyway.) That way it's more or less clear both what the structure of your class is, and the code will compile after being copy-pasted and thus need less modifications by people trying to answer.

Comment: fixed thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I/we are having to make some assumptions about what you want to do -- for instance, in your example, the 'to' values are small, simple integers, but we have no indication that all 'to' values are in that category.

I recommend creating a HashMap entry for each 'to' value; the index is either an Integer or a Float (or a double) that corresponds to your 'to' entry, and the value holds an int that you can increment each time that 'to' value is encountered.

If that doesn't solve your problem, perhaps you can explain more of what you need.

Comment: I will try using HashMaps, but for the record my integer values are rather small. Nothing over 100.

Comment: Suppose I create an object "v.neighbors.add(new vertexWeight (to, 1))" in an array. How would I go back to it and change the 1 after a few lines of code? That is the essence of my problem.

Comment: For each 'to' object, determine if it is already in the HashMap.  If it is, increment the corresponding int.  If it is not, create its key, and set the int to 1 (it's the first one you've encountered).  If you *know* no 'to' values are over N, where N is small enough, create an array of N integers and set them all to 0; then use the 'to' value as an index into that array; increment when you find one, and you have an array of the number of times each int was encountered (IF they are small and integer).